# Autofill a text form value after select an option form

Tags: html, forms, input

I have 2 form

```
<select>
  <option>Rose</option>
  <option>Violet</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<input type="text" value="Autofill here" />
```

if users select Rose, a text form value will be "Red" automatically.

if users select Violet, a text form value will be "Blue" automatically.

Did you have a simple sample for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery, add change event to select, set selected value to text input. Note: you need to add Blue Red to select option in HTML first:

```js
$('#myselect').on('change', function(){
  $('#myinput').val($(this).val());
})

// init
$('#myselect').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="Red">Rose</option>
  <option value="Blue">Violet</option>
</select>

<input id="myinput" type="text" value="Autofill here" />
```

Comment: I think OP wants the value to be printed in the textbox, rather than changing the color of the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Basic idea using JQuery:

Html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="colorPicker">
  <option value="Red">Rose</option>
  <option value="Blue">Violet</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //when the select changes:
    $('.colorPicker').on("change", function(){
        //set the value of the input to the value of the select.
            $('.colorDisplay').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

In principle, we bind a function to change event of the select. Using a class to identify both the input field and the select. When a user selects an option, the input is automatically updated to be the value of the option selected.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3oqx0s40/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var e = document.getElementById("selectFlower");
e.addEventListener("change", function(){
    $('#inp').css('color', $('#selectFlower').val());
});

<select id="selectFlower">
      <option value="red">Rose</option>
      <option value="blue">Violet</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="inp" value="Autofill here" />
```

Comment: Its nice answer, but what I need is an autofill value of text form.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Vanilla JavaScript**

```js
var e = document.getElementById("selectFlower");
e.addEventListener("change", function() {

  var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("inp").value = val;

});

// To show preselected value

var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("inp").value = val;
```

```html
<select id="selectFlower">
  <option>Rose</option>
  <option>Violet</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="inp" value="Autofill here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="Rose">Rose</option>
  <option value="Violet">Violet</option>
</select>

<input id="test" type="text" value="Autofill here" />
```

The JS code is

```
var selection = document.getElementById("sel");
document.getElementById("test").value(selection.options[ selection.selectedIndex ].value)
```

Make from this JS code a function and add it to `input` with onChange attribute